# How to replace rows by their means in a multiple columns groupby pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that contains user ratings for points of interest. I need to replace rows for the same place (`attr_name`) by the same user (`reviewer_link`) in the same country (`reviewer_demographics_residence_state`) by the average rating (`review_rate`) the user gave. So

```
csv_df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict({'reviewer_link': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                       'reviewer_demographics_residence_state': [
                         'greece', 'greece', 'greece', 'greece', 'greece',
                         'italy', 'greece', 'greece'],
                       'attr_name': ['uffizi', 'uffizi', 'uffizi',
                                     'uffizi', 'uffizi2', 'uffizi',
                                     'uffizi', 'uffizi', ],
                       'review_rate': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1],
                       'dummy': [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]
                       }))
csv_df['review_rate'] = csv_df.groupby(
  ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link', 'attr_name'])[
  'review_rate'].transform('mean')
print(csv_df)
```

correctly calculates the means:

```
   reviewer_link reviewer_demographics_residence_state attr_name  review_rate  dummy
0              1                                greece    uffizi          1.0      1
1              2                                greece    uffizi          2.0      2
2              3                                greece    uffizi          2.5      3
3              4                                greece    uffizi          2.5      4
4              1                                greece   uffizi2          4.0      4
5              2                                 italy    uffizi          3.0      3
6              3                                greece    uffizi          2.5      2
7              4                                greece    uffizi          2.5      1
```

but I can't quite wrap my head around replacing the rows in the original dataframe with those means (so have one row per country/user/PoI, having the mean as rating)

EDIT: expected output (hand made):

```
reviewer_demographics_residence_state reviewer_link attr_name  review_rate  dummy
greece                                1             uffizi             1.0      1  
greece                                1             uffizi2            4.0      2  
greece                                2             uffizi             2.0      3  
greece                                3             uffizi             2.5      4  
greece                                4             uffizi             2.5      4  
italy                                 2             uffizi             3.0      3
```

so the dummy column keeps the first value. Of course the csv_df contains much more columns

Comment: I need to also drop those rows

Comment: So I think the one liner you gave just replaces the values while I need to drop the "duplicate" rows and replace them by identical rows that have the mean rating

Comment: OK, then need `csv_df.groupby(
  ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link',
   'attr_name']).mean().reset_index()` ?

Comment: Nope - this takes the mean of other columns too

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand.

Comment: If there are other numerical columns this replaces their values by their mean - it would not matter mostly but I am interested in a solution that would only calculate the means of the `review_rate` in each group then replace the rows of each group by the first one say - having the mean in `review_rate`

Comment: Ok, then use `csv_df.groupby( ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link', 'attr_name'])['review_rate'].mean().reset_index()`

Comment: This one drops the extra columns - see it's not trivial - especially if one is new to pandas like me :) Edited adding an extra `dummy` column to illustrate

Comment: I understand now, but unfortuantely there are only these solutions - `transform` - it create duplicated values, but no column is dropped or aggregate like in your question, but need for each column define aggregate function.

Comment: Then please reopen as maybe some one can come up with a different idea. Probably manually dropping the "duplicate" rows as second step ?

Comment: I have a idea - can you add expected output with multiple columns? Do you need `csv_df.groupby( ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link', 'attr_name']).agg({'review_rate':'mean', 'dummy col':'first', 'another col':'first'}).reset_index()` ?

Comment: Hmmm - `ValueError: cannot insert attr_name, already exists`

Comment: Try `csv_df.groupby( ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link', 'attr_name']).agg({'review_rate':'mean', 'dummy col':'first', 'another col':'first'}).rename_axis(('a','b','c')).reset_index()`

Comment: `csv_df = csv_df.groupby(
      ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state', 'reviewer_link',
       'attr_name']).agg(
      {'review_rate': 'mean', 'dummy': 'first'}).reset_index()` - works excellent - please post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need aggregate by `mean` column `review_rate` and all another columns which need in output by `first`:

```
csv_df = (csv_df.groupby ['reviewer_demographics_residence_state',
                           'reviewer_link', 'attr_name'])
               .agg( {'review_rate': 'mean', 'dummy': 'first'})
               .reset_index())

print (csv_df)

  reviewer_demographics_residence_state  reviewer_link attr_name  review_rate  \
0                                greece              1    uffizi          1.0   
1                                greece              1   uffizi2          4.0   
2                                greece              2    uffizi          2.0   
3                                greece              3    uffizi          2.5   
4                                greece              4    uffizi          2.5   
5                                 italy              2    uffizi          3.0   

   dummy  
0      1  
1      4  
2      2  
3      3  
4      4  
5      3
```